# How to config a special button with image and subtitle

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I would like to generate the following html button with typoscript, but not yet successful after trying for hours. The image is the page image, title the page title and subtitle the page subtitle. May someone can help?

```
<div class="left_links">
  <a href="/verhalen-van-klanten.html"><img src="/images/layout/klanten.png"></a>
  <table class="left_text active">
    <tr><td><a href="/verhalen-van-klanten.html"><font style="font-size: 16px;">Verhalen van klanten</font></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="/verhalen-van-klanten.html">Wat vind jij?</a></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have used the following typoscript:

```
  tipmenu = HMENU
  tipmenu.special = directory
  tipmenu.special.value = 8
  tipmenu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      wrap = <div class="left_links">|</div>

      NO {
        linkWrap = |<table class="left_text">
        after {
          wrap = <tr><td>|</td></tr></table>
          field = subtitle
        }      
      }
    }
  }
```

That generates the following html:

```
<div class="left_links">
  <a href="tips/verhalen-van-klanten/" >Verhalen van klanten</a>
  <table class="left_text">
    <tr><td>Wat vind jij?</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So it is still missing the image, the title is at the wrong position and the link around the subtitle is missing?

Comment: Using table for that is maybe not the best option for that. Why don't you use span-tags für your additional informations from the table and encapsulate all with a single a-tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your expected output is on multiple items, but the following code should do what you want.

But please reconsider your menu: `<font>` and `<table>`? That's how you did menus 15 years ago. Today we have HTML5 and CSS - there is no need for those ugly tags for formatting.

```
tipmenu = HMENU
tipmenu {
    special = directory
    special.value = 8
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <div class="left_links">|</div>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            # uncomment if needed
            # allWrap = <div class="left_links_one">|</div>
            beforeImgLink = 1
            beforeImg = GIFBUILDER
            beforeImg {
                XY = 80,80s
                10 = IMAGE
                10.file {
                    # load the first image in the media field
                    import = uploads/media/
                    import.field = media
                    import.listNum = 0
                    height = 80
                    width = 80m
                }
            }
            linkWrap = <table class="left_text"><tr><td><font style="font-size: 16px;">|</font></td></tr>
            after.cObject = COA
            after.cObject {
                30 = TEXT
                30.field = subtitle
                30.typolink.parameter.field = uid
                30.wrap = <tr><td>|</td></tr>
                wrap = |</table>
            }
        }
    }
}
```